# visual studio android designer freeze

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm getting started with Xamarin.Android in Visual Studio 2015, making a first “hello world” project.

The following problem occurs:

I opened Main.axml and try to switch between source and designer, but designer hung (freeze).
First try to switch – ok, but after 7 trying – freeze.

> Why designer hung after switching from source?

My soft configuration:

```
Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.
NET Framework 4.6.01038.
Xamarin 4.2.2.11.
Xamarin.Android 7.0.2.42.
Windows 10, x64.
Hard configuration: Intel Core i7-4790 4GHz. RAM 16GB.
```